# How can i fix this if..else condition to give me the true value in Java?

Tags: java

So i've been struggling for 2 days now to try to make this work ! and yet without a result. 
What i'm trying to do is a homework which states that: ***A company will make an offer to those buyers who buy more than 10 products***. So if they buy 10 products the offer will be 20% off and so on.

- **Programming Language used:** Java
- **The goal:** Is that the user will give the number of the products they/clients bought and all the program will do is give how % off the price will be.
- **The problem is** that i try to print the price , for ex: 
  If they buy 20 products or more they get 30% off *

  else if(x>=20)
  a=price*(100/30);
  System.out.println("... " + a);*

And the result this gives me is the same result from the first condition:

```
if( x >= 10 ){  
a = price * 100/20; 
System.out.println("...." +a);
```

which means this is not it's true value.

I have tried removing the brackets , separating the price and offer like ( b = (100/20); a = price * b) and it didn't work ,how can i fix that?

```
**Scanner sasi = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println (Kerkesa);
 int x = sasi.nextInt();       

 if( x >= 10 ){
 a = price * (100/20);
System.out.println("...." +a);
}
else if ( x >= 20){
a = price* (100/30);
System.out.println("..." + a);
}
else if ( x >= 50 ){
a = price * (100/40);
System.out.println("..." +a);
}
else if ( x >= 100 ){
a = price * (100/50);
System.out.println("... " + a);
}
else {
System.out.print("...");
}**
```

Comment: I think you need to learn about percents first

Comment: should be reverse `price * 20 / 100`? It's a math problem

Comment: The math is `(price * x) - (price * x * (100/discountValue))` that should give you the new price with the % discounted

Comment: I did fix it , the problem was at the condition and not math ! Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, I think you should reverse the order of if conditions:

```
if (x >= 100) {
  ...
} else if (x >= 50) {
  ...
} else if (x >= 20) {
  ...
} else { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

First i'd like to thank everyone who tried to help me in the comments , to everyone who commented id say a big thank you.

The problem was that i set the condition like this :

```
if ( x >=10 )
....
```

Which means for every number greater than 10 the program would execute the code.And i was giving number greater than
 10 , like 20 , 30 etc. That's why it was giving me the same result every time !

**What i had to do was this :**

```
if ( x >= 10 && x < 20 ) 
....
```

Again thank's everyone! xD